# Conditioning on expectation?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

> In a large population of patients, 20% have early stage cancer, 10% have advanced stage cancer, and the >other 70% do not have cancer. Six patients from this population are randomly selected.
>   Calculate the expected number of selected patients with advanced stage cancer, given that at least one >of the selected patients has early stage cancer.

[image]

Can someone explain to me the solution step by step? I am completely lost... I mean I am guessing X and Y are binomial since we have  "large population", But I am lost from the line in solution starting "From conditioning on whether or not..."

Comment: The are using the LTE: For an event $A$ in the sample space, the *law of total expectation* reads $E(Y)=P(A)E(Y|A)+P(A^c)E(Y|A^c)$. Very useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$E(Y)=E(Y|A)P(A)+E(Y|A^c)P(A^c)$$  [Law_of_total_expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation)

$A=\{X\geq 1\}$ so $A^c=\{X < 1\} =\{X=0\}$

$$E(Y)=E(Y|X\geq 1)P(X\geq 1)+E(Y|X=0)P(X=0)$$

$$E(Y)-E(Y|X=0)P(X=0)=E(Y|X\geq 1)P(X\geq 1)$$

$$\frac{E(Y)-E(Y|X=0)P(X=0)}{P(X\geq 1)}=E(Y|X\geq 1)$$